# Speed over style in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, methods, label, code-cleanup

What is more important readability or speed?

**Example:**

Say you create a lot of resources in one method and if some operation fails you have to free the ones which were successfully created. Would you rather do that in a general clean up label which will free any resource or free the created resources after the failed operation?

**Style 1:**

```
void foo(void)
{
   void* res1, res2, res3;
   res1 = malloc(1);
   if(res1 == NULL)
     return; //operation failed

   res2 = malloc(1);
   if(res2 == NULL)
   {
       free(res1);
       return;
   }

   res3 = malloc(1);
   if(res3 == NULL)
   {
       free(res1);
       free(res2);
       return;
   }
}
```

**Style 2:**

```
void foo(void)
{
   void* res1 = NULL, *res2 = NULL, *res3 = NULL;
   res1 = malloc(1);
   if(res1 == NULL)
     goto lbl_clean_up; //operation failed

   res2 = malloc(1);
   if(res2 == NULL)
   {
       goto lbl_clean_up;
   }

   res3 = malloc(1);
   if(res3 == NULL)
   {
       goto lbl_clean_up;
   }
lbl_clean_up:
   {
       if(res1 != NULL)
          free(res1);
       if(res2 != NULL)
          free(res2);
       if(res3 != NULL)
          free(res3);
       return;
}
```

Now should I rather use Style 1 or Style 2 ? Style 2 has more redundant if-statements but looks much more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would prefer a variant of the second method.  Using `goto` to jump to cleanup code is a clean way of handling things.

To improve on this, calling `free` on a NULL pointer is a no-op so no need for the extra `if`s:

```
void foo(void)
{
   void* res1 = NULL, *res2 = NULL, *res3 = NULL;
   res1 = malloc(1);
   if(res1 == NULL)
     goto lbl_clean_up; //operation failed

   res2 = malloc(1);
   if(res2 == NULL)
   {
       goto lbl_clean_up;
   }

   res3 = malloc(1);
   if(res3 == NULL)
   {
       goto lbl_clean_up;
   }
lbl_clean_up:
   free(res3);
   free(res2);
   free(res1);

   return;
}
```

It's also good practice to release the resources in the reverse order that they were allocated in.  You can further use this when making use of multiple labels.  For example:

```
void foo(void)
{
   FILE *f1, *f2, *f3;

   f1 = fopen("infile1", "r");
   if (f1 == NULL)
     goto cleanup1;

   f2 = fopen("infile2", "r");
   if (f2 == NULL)
     goto cleanup2;

   f3 = fopen("outfile", "w");
   if (f3 == NULL)
     goto cleanup3;

   // do something

   close(f3);
cleanup3:
   close(f2);
cleanup2:
   close(f1);
cleanup1:
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That reverse order thing is great to avoid the if statements and keep the code clean.

Answer (score -2):

The speed difference in the case of failed malloc does not matter.

Style 1 has one much more serious problem : multiple returns. Such a functions are (IMO) much more difficult to read and it is much more difficult to change the function return type